# Can SQL server Developer edition be installed on Windows 7 Home Premium?

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008, windows-7

We are planning to buy OS and RDBMS for our organization. I wanted to know whether SQL server 2008 Developer Edition:

[http://www.amazon.com/Developer-Edtn-2008-32-bit-English/dp/B003KWQBQ2/ref=sr_1_2?s=software&ie=UTF8&qid=1349233840&sr=1-2&keywords=SQL+Server+Developer+Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003KWQBQ2)

be installed on Windows 7 Home Premium:

[http://www.amazon.com/Windows-Premium-64bit-System-Builder/dp/B004Q0PT3I/ref=sr_1_1?s=software&ie=UTF8&qid=1349234718&sr=1-1&keywords=windows+7+os](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004Q0PT3I)

Or are they both incompatible? Please suggest your thoughts. I know it installs on Windows 7 Ultimate because I have it on my machine but not sure about Home Premium.

Comment: For organizations, why would you be on Home? Why not Pro?

Comment: @Marc B: Because it is very small organization. Just 2-3 people and we don't want to spend that much money on Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Hardware and Software requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28SQL.105%29.aspx) seem to indicate that it is supported.